# Difference between test and check tasks in Gradle

Tags: gradle, gradle-task

My `build.gradle` is as follows:

```groovy
group 'groupName'
version 'version'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    . . .
}

dependencies {
    . . .
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

In Gradle when doing `./gradlew tasks` I receive

```
Verification tasks
------------------
check - Runs all checks.
test - Runs the unit tests.
```

What is the difference between these two tasks? The output of `./gradlew check` is identical to `./gradlew test`.

```
andrewgazelka $ ./gradlew check

> Task :test FAILED

MathTest > testX FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError at MathTest.java:40

MathTest > testY FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError at MathTest.java:55

SimulatorTest > testZ FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at SimulatorTest.java:71

30 tests completed, 3 failed


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///Users/andrewgazelka/IdeaProjects/RobotCode2018/build/reports/tests/test/index.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
andrewgazelka $ ./gradlew test

> Task :test FAILED

MathTest > testX FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError at MathTest.java:40

MathTest > testY FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError at MathTest.java:55

SimulatorTest > testZ FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at SimulatorTest.java:71

30 tests completed, 3 failed


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///Users/andrewgazelka/IdeaProjects/RobotCode2018/build/reports/tests/test/index.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

From what I understand, `./gradle test` ⊆ `./gradle check`. Is this correct?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The Gradle `check` task depends on the `test` task which means `test` is executed before `check` is run. The [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) states that check performs all verification tasks in the project, including `test` and also tasks plugins add to the project:

[image]

If you for example add the [checkstyle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/checkstyle_plugin.html) plugin to your project you can either run its tasks `checkstyleMain` and `checkstyleTest` individually or execute a full project verification using `check`. In this case the tasks `test`, `checkstyleMain` and `checkstyleTest` would be run.
Whereas `test` always just executes your unit tests.

Comment: One may add that `test` is a task that actually does something, while `check` is a so-called lifecycle task, that only bundles other tasks. The most common lifecycle task is `build`.